# php multi-dimensional array remove duplicate

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Not sure if this question is a duplicate in need of removal, but I couldn't find the answer elsewhere so I'll have a go at asking.

I've got a 2d array that looks as follows:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => dave
        [1] => jones
        [2] => c@b.c
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => john
        [1] => jones
        [2] => a@b.c

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => bruce
        [1] => finkle
        [2] => c@b.c
    )
)
```

I'd like to remove those with duplicate emails. So in the above example I'd like to just remove either [][0] or [][2]. I'm not worried about checking against names or anything like that, I just need the sub arrays to be deduplicated based on a single value.

At the moment I have something like this

```
  if(is_array($array) && count($array)>0){
  foreach ($array as $subarray) {
    $duplicateEmail[$subarray[2]] = isset($duplicateEmail[$subarray[2]]);
    unset($duplicateEmail[$subarray[2]]);
   }
  }
```

but it just ain't right. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A quick solution which uses the uniqueness of array indexes:

```
$newArr = array();
foreach ($array as $val) {
    $newArr[$val[2]] = $val;    
}
$array = array_values($newArr);
```

Notice 1: As visible from above, the last match for an email address is used instead of the first. This can be changed by replacing the second line with

```
foreach (array_reverse($array) as $val) {
```

Notice 2: The indexes in the resulting array are somewhat mixed up. But I guess this doesn't matter...

Comment: your 'for' should have been a 'foreach' but otherwise it works well, thanks.

Comment: @Cassy - Just turned this into a function for myself in a little app I'm coding, thanks for it!

Comment: Thanks man that did the trick .Don't know why i missed this answer at first Now issue solved! :)

Answer (score 15):

Much Simpler Solution.

```
$unique = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $array)));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($unique);
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. That just checks for unique arrays rather than their properties. Appreciate you giving it another go though.

Answer (score 8):

The user comments for [array_unique()](http://php.net/array_unique) have a few solutions to this. For example

> ```
>     function multi_unique($array) {
>         foreach ($array as $k=>$na)
>             $new[$k] = serialize($na);
>         $uniq = array_unique($new);
>         foreach($uniq as $k=>$ser)
>             $new1[$k] = unserialize($ser);
>         return ($new1);
>     }
> ```

*from http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#57202.*

Comment: which covers the whole sub-array rather than individual values if i'm not mistaken

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = array(
    array('dave','jones','c@b.c'),
    array('dave','jones','a@c.d'),
    array('dave','jones','c@b.c'),
    array('dave','jones','e@v.d'),
    array('dave','jones','a@c.d')   
);

$copy = $array; // create copy to delete dups from
$usedEmails = array(); // used emails

for( $i=0; $i<count($array); $i++ ) {

    if ( in_array( $array[$i][2], $usedEmails ) ) {
        unset($copy[$i]);
    }
    else {
        $usedEmails[] = $array[$i][2];
    }

}

print_r($copy);
```

Answer (score 1):

User SORT_REGULAR as second parameter.

```
$uniqueArray = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposition:

```
protected function arrayUnique($array, $preserveKeys = false)
{
    $uniqueArray = array();
    $hashes = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (true === is_array($value)) {
            $uniqueArray[$key] = $this->arrayUnique($value, $preserveKeys);

        } else {
            $hash = md5($value);

            if (false === isset($hashes[$hash])) {
                if ($preserveKeys) {
                    $uniqueArray[$key] = $value;
                } else {
                    $uniqueArray[] = $value;
                }

                $hashes[$hash] = $hash;
            }
        }
    }

    return $uniqueArray;
}
```