# Creating unique arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array such as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1355698
            [comment] => hello
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1355699
            [comment] => hey
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1355700
            [comment] => hello
        )

)
```

The `id` will always be unique, so the uniqueness of the element will be based on the subarray's value of `comment`. In this case, `array[0]` has a duplicate `array[2]`. (I wonder if there is a better way to phrase this explaination).

`array_unique()` will not work in this case. Is there an alternative? Thanks!

Comment: I believe this will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442230/php-getting-unique-values-of-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: Follow Mark1inLA's answer and it leads to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861682/php-multi-dimensional-array-remove-duplicate - the accepted answer on that question should do exactly as you ask.

Comment: The accepted answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861682/php-multi-dimensional-array-remove-duplicate would use the comment as the array key. I don't think its a good solution for the problem, since a comment might have hundreds of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new array with id and comment as key=>value pairs, then `array_unique()`.

Comment: like: `array( 1344698 => "hello", 1355699, => "hey", 1355700 => "hello");`

Comment: If you wind up with this solution, you'll also have a convenient way to access the comments without iterating.

Answer (score 0):

```
$uniqueArray = array();
foreach ($nonUniqueArray as $i) {
    $uniqueArray[$i['comment']] = $i;
}

// optionally:
// $uniqueArray = array_values($uniqueArray);

var_dump($uniqueArray);
```