# applying array_unique

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have code to get the address which is separated by space and then fetching area details about that address so each time sql result is stored in array  "resultArray"  and that result is pushed to another array "returnArray" which is then displayed in the format of json.I want to remove duplicate area_id in returnArray so I used "array_unique" but it's not working .Please give some suggestion.

Sample Code:

```
    <?php
    include_once 'main.php';
    $dac = new Main();
    $add = $_POST['address'];
    $noLines = sizeof($add);
    $resultArray=array();
    $returnArray=array();
    $returnArrayMain=array();

    while ($noLines>0)
    {
        $resultArray=array();
        $result = $dac->area_detail($add[$noLines-1]);
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
     {  
            $resultArray[]=array('area_id' => $row['area_id'],'area_name' =>       $row['area_name'],'area_GISlat'=>$row['area_GISlat'],'area_GISlon'=>$row['area_GISlon']);
     }
          array_push($returnArray, $resultArray) ;  
          $noLines = $noLines-1; 

    }

      $returnArrayMain = array_unique($returnArray);
      echo json_encode($returnArrayMain);
 ?>
```

Comment: Please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2442315/3647441

Comment: I have tried method they mentioned but it's not working because it's inside two array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution with a testing `associative array`:

```
// this is testing array as you are using:
$resultArray = array(   
    array(
    'area_id' => 12,
    'area_name' => 'test',
    'area_GISlat'=>'test2',
    'area_GISlon'=>'test3'),
    array(
    'area_id' => 11,
    'area_name' => 'test',
    'area_GISlat'=>'test2',
    'area_GISlon'=>'test3'),
    array(
    'area_id' => 12,
    'area_name' => 'test',
    'area_GISlat'=>'test2',
    'area_GISlon'=>'test3')
    );

// take a temporary arry
$temporaryArr  = array();

// initialize key's array
$arrayKey  = array();

foreach ( $resultArray as $key => $values ) {
    if ( !in_array($values, $temporaryArr) ) {
        $temporaryArr[] = $values; // store values in temporary array
        $arrayKey[$key] = true; // store all keys in another array
    }
}

// now use array_intersect_key function for intersect both array.
$requiredArr = array_intersect_key($resultArray, $arrayKey);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($requiredArr);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [area_id] => 12
            [area_name] => test
            [area_GISlat] => test2
            [area_GISlon] => test3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [area_id] => 11
            [area_name] => test
            [area_GISlat] => test2
            [area_GISlon] => test3
        )    
)
```

Removed duplicate `arrays`.

**From PHP Manual:**

[array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) — Computes the intersection of arrays using keys for comparison

**Side note:**

Also add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$returnArrayMain = uniqueAssocArray($returnArray, 'area_id');
echo json_encode($returnArrayMain);

function uniqueAssocArray($array, $uniqueKey) {
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        return array();
    }
    $uniqueKeys = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        $groupBy=$item[$uniqueKey];
        if (isset( $uniqueKeys[$groupBy]))
        {
            //compare $item with $uniqueKeys[$groupBy] and decide if you 
            //want to use the new item
            $replace= ... 
        }
        else
        {
            $replace=true;
        }
        if ($replace) $uniqueKeys[$groupBy] = $item;   
    }
    return $uniqueKeys;
}
```

Comment: sry forgot to give function.. i have added function in my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$returnArrayMain = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $resultArray)));
```