# Group arrays according to their keys and remove duplicates (2 dimensional arrays)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, duplicates, grouping

I have three arrays as follows:

```
$a=Array ( [0] => 'member0' [1] => 'member1' [2] => 'member2' [3] => 'member1');
$b=Array ( [0] => 'id0' [1] => 'id1' [2] => 'id2' [3] => 'id1');
$c=Array ( [0] => 'tf0' [1] => 'tf1' [2] => 'tf2' [3] => 'tf1');
```

I would like to group their values according to their keys in a 2 dimensional array to output the following:

```
$2dim_array=array(array('member0','id0','tf0'),array('member1','id1','tf1'),array('member2','id2','tf2'),array('member1','id1','tf1'));
```

After, I would like to remove any duplicate array inside of the previous 2 dimensional array and output something like this:

```
$remove_duplicates=array(array('member0','id0','tf0'),array('member1','id1','tf1'),array('member2','id2','tf2'));
```

How can I do this?

Note: The arrays of this example only contain 3 elements each, but the length of my arrays can be variable (undefined number of keys).

Comment: Not sure why I was voted down in this question...I think it can be useful for other people as well...

Comment: agree with you. It will definitely help others :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for group according to keys:

```
$a = array('member0','member1','member2','member1');
$b = array('id0','id1','id2','id1');
$c = array('tf0','tf1','tf2','tf1');

$merge = array_map(function($a1, $b1, $c1){
    return array($a1, $b1, $c1);
}, $a, $b, $c);
```

For removing duplicate records you can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

```
// remove duplicates by using array_map() and `array_unique()` for multidimensional array
$duplicateRemoved = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $merge)));

// rearrange the array
$rearrangeArray = array_values($duplicateRemoved);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($rearrangeArray);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => member0
            [1] => id0
            [2] => tf0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => member1
            [1] => id1
            [2] => tf1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => member2
            [1] => id2
            [2] => tf2
        )

)
```

Comment: upvoted for your rearrange index but I still not sure its necessity but I know if you have added it then there must be a reason ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP's [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function

```
$a = ['member0','member1','member2','member1'];
$b = ['id0','id1','id2','id1'];
$c = ['tf0','tf1','tf2','tf1'];

// run three arrays in loop with array_map
$result = array_map(function($a1, $b1, $c1){
        return [ $a1, $b1, $c1];
}, $a, $b, $c);

// get unique records
$result = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $result)));
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);
```

Unique record link:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/2442315/4198099

**output**:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => member0
            [1] => id0
            [2] => tf0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => member1
            [1] => id1
            [2] => tf1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => member2
            [1] => id2
            [2] => tf2
        )

)
```

Hope it will help you :-)

Comment: @devpro: Yes my friend. I missed it in earlier shot :-)

Comment: Thanks Brother :-) Why you have used array_values at the end in your answer?

Comment: for rearrange the array index.

Comment: Yes but array_map will auto assign index from 0 then I think no need of it. Let me correct if I am wrong.