# Unique values multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have made a multidimensional array and want to filter duplicate values. I tried several solutions which i have found on the web but they don't work well. see my code  below how i'm making my array.

```
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    item = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

    //Get Aanvrager and add to array
    if (item.get_item("Aanvrager")) {
        aanvragerslijst.push({
            id: item.get_item("ID"),
            value: item.get_item("Aanvrager")
        });
    }

    //&& jQuery.inArray(item.get_item("Afdelingshoofd"), afdelingshoofdlijst) == 0)


    //Get Afdelingshoofd and add to array
    if (item.get_item("Afdelingshoofd")) {
        afdelingshoofdlijst.push({
            id: item.get_item("ID"),
            value: item.get_item("Afdelingshoofd").get_lookupValue()
        });
    }     
}


$.each(afdelingshoofdlijst, function (key, value) {
    if (value) {
        $('#LKAfdelingshoofd').append($("<option/>", {
            value: value.value,
            text: value.value
        }));
    }
});
```

Comment: It would be better if you can simplify the problem to the bare minimal, abstract it from your code, give us the input and expected output and a demo to reproduce the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get only unique items in a multidimensional array with JavaScript/jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355058/how-to-get-only-unique-items-in-a-multidimensional-array-with-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
function getUniqueValues(array, key) {
var result = new Set();
array.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        result.add(item[key]);
    }
});
return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
var uniqueArr = getUniqueValues(yourArr,keyYouWant)
```

Reference:[Get Unique Values in a MultiDim Array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100768/generating-an-array-of-unique-values-of-a-specific-property-in-an-object-array)

Good Luck