# Unique Array by Value

Tags: php, arrays

```
$email_users[] = $row;

print_r($email_users);
```

Result:

```
Array ( 

[0] => Array ( 
[user_id] => 87436 
[username] => Admin 
[user_email] => email@online.us 
[user_lang] => de 
[allowed] => 1 ) 

[1] => Array ( 
[user_id] => 68013 
[username] => Testuser 
[user_email] => email2@online.us 
[user_lang] => de 
[allowed] => 1 ) 

[2] => Array ( 
[user_id] => 68013 
[username] => Testuser 
[user_email] => email2@online.us 
[user_lang] => de 
[allowed] => 1 ) 

)
```

As you can see, the user_id 68013 is double. I have to remove the double Array. **The Result should look like this**:

```
Array ( 

[0] => Array ( 
[user_id] => 87436 
[username] => Admin 
[user_email] => email@online.us 
[user_lang] => de 
[allowed] => 1 ) 

[1] => Array ( 
[user_id] => 68013 
[username] => Testuser 
[user_email] => email2@online.us 
[user_lang] => de 
[allowed] => 1 ) 

)
```

I read and tried several solutions I found on stack. For example:

[How to get unique value in multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408482/how-to-get-unique-value-in-multidimensional-array)

```
$email_users[] = $row;

$user_ids = array();
foreach ($email_users as $h) {
$user_ids[] = $h['user_id'];
}
$email_users = array_unique($user_ids);

print_r($email_users);
```

But the print_r is only:

```
Array ( [0] => 87436 [1] => 68013 )
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `array_unique($your_array,SORT_REGULAR)`.

Comment: I guess you get your data from a SQL-query - could you post that query, and have you tried SELECT DISTINCT ?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Select Distinct want work because its a loop. Thank you

Comment: @Uchiha Can you give me a better example? thank you

Comment: Simply use `print_r(array_unique($email_users,SORT_REGULAR));` From where you were getting this array

Comment: @Uchiha like a charm. I will accept the answer from Bharat, its the same but I have no accept button for your comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: @Uchiha but thats not me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get distinct value from your query. Use SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tablename and you will get Distinct value. 
Or use $email_users= array_unique($email_users, SORT_REGULAR);

Comment: Distinct want work, because its a loop but your SORT_REGULAR is fine :) thank you