# How to get one value from duplicates values in Multidimensional array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array some values are duplicate and some unique.

duplicate values are parent and unique values are child of duplicate values.

Multidimensional array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [L1_ID] => 21
            [L1_ATTR_DESC] => Project Overview
            [L2_ATTR_DESC] => Project Status
            [L3_ATTR_DESC] => Ready
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [L1_ID] => 21
            [L1_ATTR_DESC] => Project Overview
            [L2_ATTR_DESC] => Project Status
            [L3_ATTR_DESC] => Pending
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [L1_ID] => 21
            [L1_ATTR_DESC] => Project Overview
            [L2_ATTR_DESC] => Project Status
            [L3_ATTR_DESC] => Completed
        )
     [3] => Array
        (
            [L1_ID] => 21
            [L1_ATTR_DESC] => Project Overview
            [L2_ATTR_DESC] => Project Quality
            [L3_ATTR_DESC] => Independ
        )
       [4] => Array
        (
            [L1_ID] => 21
            [L1_ATTR_DESC] => Project Overview
            [L2_ATTR_DESC] => Project Quality
            [L3_ATTR_DESC] => G+1
        )
)
```

I want to show duplicate value print one time and unique value should be child of duplicate values.

Expected Output - Like this :

```
-Project Status      -Project Build
    --Ready             --Independ
    --Pending           --G+1
    --Completed
```

Comment: okay, and what did you try for now? did it not work as intended?

Comment: Actually, I am confused how to do this.

Comment: use loop and condition to store like you want

Comment: To begin, your multidimensional array isn't descriptive enough (or understandable) for the array to be built into the structure you wanted. I suppose if you mean "Project Build" to be "Project Quality", then you simply just need to loop through the array, check "L2_ATTR_DESC" and sort it into another array.

Comment: @ManishTiwari which part confuses you?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408482/how-to-get-unique-value-in-multidimensional-array

Comment: see this logic: this is not complete but almost, just see the code [https://3v4l.org/JuPIa](https://3v4l.org/JuPIa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for check see whats happen: [Online Link](https://3v4l.org/SaiS9)

```
$ps = array();
foreach($arr as $value){
    $index = str_replace(" ", "", strtolower($value['L2_ATTR_DESC']));
    $ps[$index][] = $value['L3_ATTR_DESC'];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($ps);
```

From now you can design it in your way.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is commonly called "index array". You can check [array_column](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-column.php), which I think will fill your need.

```
$array = array(/* multidimensional array */);
$index = array_column($array, L3_ATTR_DESC);
```

`$index` will contain an array of values associated with L3_ATTR_DESC in $array.

Comment: why you think? why not confident?

Answer (score 0):

Working [demo](https://eval.in/573192). You can use foreach Statement

```
foreach($a as $arg) {
   $tmp[$arg['L1_ATTR_DESC']][$arg['L2_ATTR_DESC']][] = $arg['L3_ATTR_DESC'];
}

$output = array();
foreach($tmp as $type => $labels) {
$output[] = array(
    'L1_ATTR_DESC' => $type,
    'L2_ATTR_DESC' => $labels
  );
}
```

I think you expecting output like these

```
 Array
(

     [L1_ATTR_DESC] => Project Overview
     [L2_ATTR_DESC] => Array
         (
            [Project Status] => Array
                (
                     [0] => Ready
                     [1] => Pending
                     [2] => Completed
                )

            [Project Quality] => Array
                (
                     [0] => Independ
                     [1] => G+1
                )
       )
)
```

OR

```
foreach($a as $arg)
{
    $tmp[$arg['L2_ATTR_DESC']][] = $arg['L3_ATTR_DESC'];
}
print_r($tmp);
```

Output

```
    Array
    (
        [Project Status] => Array
            (
                 [0] => Ready
                 [1] => Pending
                 [2] => Completed
            )

        [Project Quality] => Array
            (
                 [0] => Independ
                 [1] => G+1
            )
    )
```