# Php - Output all keys and unique values from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$names  = array("Accounting"=>"Peter", "Finance"=>"Joe", "Human Resource"=>"Joe");
```

and want to output all keys and unique values.

The result should be:

Peter: Accounting

Joe: Finance, Human Resource

Thanks Philip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get unique value in multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408482/how-to-get-unique-value-in-multidimensional-array)

Comment: @VasilShaddix amusingly enough that question is a duplicate of another question which is itself a duplicate of at least two more questions. It would be quite fun if one of those linked back to being a duplicate of this question `:-D` . A duplicate circle.

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty array to hold the end result and use a simple `foreach` loop like this;

```
$names  = array("Accounting"=>"Peter", "Finance"=>"Joe", "Human Resource"=>"Joe");

$resultArr = array();
foreach($names as $key => $value){
    $resultArr[$value][] = $key;
}

// display $resultArr array
var_dump($resultArr);
```

Here's a [**live demo**](https://eval.in/711820)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the keys  and values in the array using a foreach loop and print both the keys and values.

```
foreach($names as $key => $value) {
 print "$key : $value\n";
```

}