# PHP to remove duplicated values and exactly UNIQUE from multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I found many question and answer about this, but not match what i need.
i think it's similar/same to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php) but don't know why not working for this case. So please try before judging duplicates, thank you.

## array source

```
$avar = array(
0 => array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
1 => array(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,7,8,9,10),
23 => array(21,22,23,4,5,6,7,11,12,13,14,15,21));
```

## desired result

```
$avar = array(
0 => array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
1 => array(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17),
23 => array(21,22,23));
```

## PHP script

```
<?php
function super_unique($array)
{
  $result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));

  foreach ($result as $key => $value)
  {
    if ( is_array($value) )
    {
      $result[$key] = super_unique($value);
    }
  }

  return $result;
}

$result = super_unique($avar);  
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);

?>
```

similar question with answer but not solve my case:

1. [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)
2. [PHP remove duplicate values from multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598298/php-remove-duplicate-values-from-multidimensional-array)

Thank you all

Comment: are the array keys (0,1,23) fixed?

Comment: No, it's dynamic. pulling from table ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$seen = array();
foreach($avar as &$entry){
    $entry = array_unique(array_diff($entry,$seen));
    $seen = array_merge($entry,$seen);
}
unset($entry);
var_dump($avar);
```

Comment: Just wanted to post exactly the same! :)