# Delete Duplicates in Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an Array which has 3 Dimensions:

```
$data_ary[$k_0][$v_0[4]]['...'] = ...
```

In the brackets with '...' I write Parameters like "Country", "Designation", "Year" and so on. Now as I run this through a loop the values for $k_0 increases every loop by 1 and $v_0[4] always changes the specific value.

My Problem: Very often the values are duplicates across the different dimensions. For Example:

```
$data_ary[1][1]['Country'] = 'Germany';
$data_ary[1][1]['Year']    = '2017';
$data_ary[2][1]['Country'] = 'Germany';
$data_ary[2][1]['Year']    = '2017';
```

How do I delete those duplicates? I have tried array_unique() but the result was that from the 27.000 entries 26999 got deleted..

Some Example Input:

```
$data_ary[6]['GERMANY']['YEAR']      = 2017;
$data_ary[6]['GERMANY']['MONTH']     = 1;
$data_ary[6]['GERMANY']['ID']        = 6010;
$data_ary[6]['GERMANY']['COUNTRY']   = 'GERMANY';

$data_ary[7]['ITALY']['YEAR']        = 2016;
$data_ary[7]['ITALY']['MONTH']       = 4;
$data_ary[7]['ITALY']['ID']          = 52752;
$data_ary[7]['ITALY']['COUNTRY']     = 'ITALY';

$data_ary[8]['GERMANY']['YEAR']      = 2017;
$data_ary[8]['GERMANY']['MONTH']     = 1;
$data_ary[8]['GERMANY']['ID']        = 6010;
$data_ary[8]['GERMANY']['COUNTRY']   = 'GERMANY';
```

As you can See the first and the second are basically the same but differ by the value in the first bracktes.

Comment: please show some example input array for clearence.

Comment: i think your array is multidimensional, please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598298/php-remove-duplicate-values-from-multidimensional-array

Comment: @AlivetoDie I added an example. I will look again closer to the other "possible duplicates" but those solutions didnt work for me so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $data_ary)));

print_r($input);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/903355

Reference:- [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: This is working fine for me. Thank you.

Comment: @C.Henke  glad to help you :):)