# Remove duplicates array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array looks like this,

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [id] => 224983
          [name] => James
          [weight] => 0
          [bank] => Bank A
          [transaction] => 1
          [total] => 7682000000
          [reference] => Edward
          [type] => BRANCH
          [reference_id] => 222818
          [account_number] => 1220007355285
      )
  [1] => Array
      (
          [id] => 224984
          [name] => James
          [weight] => 0
          [bank] => Bank A
          [transaction] => 1
          [total] => 7682000000
          [reference] => Edward
          [type] => BRANCH
          [reference_id] => 222819
          [account_number] => 1220007355285
      )
  [3] => Array
      (
          [id] => 224985
          [name] => Maria
          [weight] => 0
          [bank] => Bank B
          [transaction] => 1
          [total] => 1500000000
          [reference] => Andrey
          [type] => BRANCH
          [reference_id] => 247620
          [account_number] => 1220000412901
      )              
)
```

When the account_number, reference, and name is same I want to remove the other one, and keep the last based on id...

Please someone help me to find out, I've been stuck here, so the output would be remove array[0] with ['id] => 224983, and the rest array would be the result

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @Eddie I've been trying using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598298/php-remove-duplicate-values-from-multidimensional-array but still same. because its multi dimentional array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php

Comment: @hungrykoala Thanks for your reply, but thats not help

Comment: Did you try it? That post contains many answers on how to remove duplicates on a multidimensional array.

Comment: use array_unique()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specifically just want to compare only three field of array than you can try below way. Which checks of duplicate and unset previous entries. Here $data is array input

```
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $id   = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $reference = $row['reference'];

    $flag = 0;
    for($i = $key + 1; $i < count($data); $i++)
    {
        if(($data[$i]['id'] == $id) && ($data[$i]['name'] == $name) && ($data[$i]['reference'] == $reference))
        {
            if($key != $i)
                unset($data[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Result would be

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 224983
            [name] => James
            [weight] => 0
            [bank] => Bank A
            [transaction] => 1
            [total] => 7682000000
            [reference] => Edward
            [type] => BRANCH
            [reference_id] => 222818
            [account_number] => 1220007355285
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 224985
            [name] => Maria
            [weight] => 0
            [bank] => Bank B
            [transaction] => 1
            [total] => 1500000000
            [reference] => Andrey
            [type] => BRANCH
            [reference_id] => 247620
            [account_number] => 1220000412901
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks, this help me out of complicated situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function, This will help to remove duplicates arrays.

```
function array_unique_multidimensional($input)
{
    $serialized = array_map('serialize', $input);
    $unique = array_unique($serialized);
    return array_intersect_key($input, $unique);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems inelegant, but I think you would need to loop through your previous array elements to check IDs. You could create a function something like this:

```
function id_exists_prior(&$my_array, $array_index) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $array_index; $i++) {
        if($my_array[$i]['id'] === $my_array[$array_index]['id']) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you can call it on any array element you wish, or loop through the whole array to check for duplicates. An example of the latter:

```
$your_array = [/*Your array data*/];
for($key = 0; $key < count($your_array); $key++) { 
    if(id_exists_prior($your_array, $key)) //Do your thing
}
```

The reason for passing the array key into the function is so that the function ONLY checks for prior duplicates.

Hope this helps!