# How to remove duplicate arrays from a multi dimensional array?

Tags: php

I have a large multidimensional array that looks like the below.

I want to remove duplicate arrays based on the ID, however, I am struggling to achieve this.

I want the duplicates to work over the entire array, so you can see that ID 1229873 is a duplicate, in the array 2021-07-07 and 2021-07-09, it should therefore be removed from 2021-07-09

How would I achieve this? array_unique has not worked for me.

```
$data = array (
'2021-07-07' => 
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 5435435,
    'homeID' => 8754,
    'match_url' => '/usa/reading-united-ac-vs-ocean-city-noreasters-fc-h2h-stats#1229873',
    'competition_id' => 5808,
    'matches_completed_minimum' => 12,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
   'id' => 1229873,
    'homeID' => 8754,
    'match_url' => '/usa/reading-united-ac-vs-ocean-city-noreasters-fc-h2h-stats#1229873',
    'competition_id' => 5808,
    'matches_completed_minimum' => 12,
      ),
),
'2021-07-09' => 
array (
    0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 3243234,
    'homeID' => 8754,
    'match_url' => '/usa/reading-united-ac-vs-ocean-city-noreasters-fc-h2h-stats#1229873',
    'competition_id' => 5808,
    'matches_completed_minimum' => 12,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
   'id' => 1229873,
    'homeID' => 8754,
    'match_url' => '/usa/reading-united-ac-vs-ocean-city-noreasters-fc-h2h-stats#1229873',
    'competition_id' => 5808,
    'matches_completed_minimum' => 12,
      ),
    ),
     );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP remove duplicate values from multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598298/php-remove-duplicate-values-from-multidimensional-array)

Comment: @Kinglish have you read the answers on that? They are _abysmally_bad.

Comment: @Sammitch - guilty. no - I should have checked, though I know it's a dupe many times over (with better options :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect case for `array_uunique()`! No wait, scratch that. The PHP devs refused to implement it for the perfectly valid reason of... [shuffles notes] "the function name looks like a typo".

[sets notes on fire]

Anyhow, you just need to iterate over that data, keep track of the IDs you've seen, and remove entries that you've already seen.

```php
$seen = [];

foreach(array_keys($data) as $i) {
    foreach(array_keys($data[$i]) as $j) {
        $id = $data[$i][$j]['id'];
        if( in_array($id, $seen) ) {
            unset($data[$i][$j]);
        } else {
            $seen[] = $id;
        }
    }
}
```

I've opted for the `foreach(array_keys(...) as $x)` approach as avoiding PHP references is *always* the sane choice.

[Run it.](https://3v4l.org/g78VA)

Answer (score -1):

I am Sure That is the way which you want to get the unique array.

```
$unique = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $data)));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($unique);
echo "</pre>";
```