# Remove duplicate values from a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php

How can I remove duplicate values from a multidimensional array in PHP like below.

I tried [Remove duplicate value in multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409182/remove-duplicate-value-in-multidimensional-array). But did not solve my problem.

```
Array(
    [0] => outdoor
    [1] => indoor
)

Array(
    [0] => indoor
)
```

Result should be a single array like below :

```
 array(outdoor,indoor);
```

Comment: Show the original array exactly, or the answer in the post mentioned should work.

Comment: @xdazz please refer top array set. this is what i get as a result array.

Comment: so you got twos arrays at first?

Comment: @xdazz yes. i'm using Advanced custom field repeater. and it gives an array like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

finally i found the result from [Remove duplicate value in multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409182/remove-duplicate-value-in-multidimensional-array). I'll share them for other users.

```
$result = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge',$result2));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `array_unique` to remove duplicates from a single array.

Use `array_merge` to combine arrays.

Try:

`array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2), SORT_REGULAR);`

Comment: what do you mean by $array1, $array2? can convert your code into example given by me

Comment: `$array1 = array( 0 => 'outdoor', 1 => 'indoor' );`
`$array2 = array( 0 => 'indoor' );`

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array(array("outdoor","indoor"),array("indoor"));

$result = array_unique($array);

print_r($result[0]);
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/123403)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
$Arr = array(array('outdoor','indoor'),array('indoor'));
$result = array_unique($Arr);

$newArr = $result[0];

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArr);
?>
```

The result will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => outdoor
    [1] => indoor
)
```

--

Thanks

Comment: this works. but does not answer my question

Comment: I edit my post. Pl try this ... Pl accept this answer if works