# Removing similar elements from a PHP array

Tags: php

I have an array structured like this:

```
$arrNames = array(

array('first'=>'John', 'last'=>'Smith', 'id'=>'1'),
array('first'=>'John', 'last'=>'Smith', 'id'=>'2'),
array('first'=>'John', 'last'=>'Smith', 'id'=>'3')

)
```

I need to remove the *similar elements* where the fist and last name are the same. Normally, I would use array_unique but the elements aren't exactly unique since each one has a unique id. I do not care which id is retained. I just need the array to look like this:

```
$arrNames = array(

array('first'=>'John', 'last'=>'Smith', 'id'=>'1') // can be any id from the original array

)
```

Is there a quick way to accomplish this? My first thought is to use something like a bubble sort but I'm wondering if there is a better (faster) way. The resulting array is being added to a drop-down list box and the duplicate entries is confusing some users. I'm using the ID to pull the record back from the DB after it is selected. Therefore, it must be included in the array.

Comment: Does the specific ID matter, or do you just need one of the several possible IDs?

Comment: `array_map()` can probably help you here...

Comment: The specific ID does not matter.

Comment: I think it is already here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861682/php-multi-dimensional-array-remove-duplicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php

  $arrNames = array(
    array('first'=>'John', 'last'=>'Smith', id=>'1'),
    array('first'=>'John', 'last'=>'Smith', id=>'2'),
    array('first'=>'John', 'last'=>'Smith', id=>'3')
  );

  $arrFound = array();
  foreach ($arrNames as $intKey => $arrPerson) {
    $arrPersonNoId = array(
      'first' => $arrPerson['first'],
      'last' => $arrPerson['last']
    );
    if (in_array($arrPersonNoId, $arrFound)) {
      unset($arrNames[$intKey]);
    } else {
      $arrFound[] = $arrPersonNoId;
    }
  }
  unset($arrFound, $intKey, $arrPerson, $arrPersonNoId);

  print_r($arrNames);
```

This definitely *works*, whether it is the *best* way is up for debate...

[Codepad](http://codepad.org/8YQwU4xA)

Comment: Was writing something like this when you posted the answer. I would concat the first and last names to a string before inserting them into `$arrFound`. `in_array()` would be more efficient that way.

Comment: @Tim I initially wrote it like that, then I realised it is prone to error - what if you have two people, `John Sonsmith` and `Johnson Smith`? Obviously this could be overcome with casing, but may not be reliable if it comes from user input...

Comment: Better solution would be to use `serialize()`.

Comment: It is already in stackoverflow :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861682/php-multi-dimensional-array-remove-duplicate

Comment: @Truth That is a good idea as it could be easily made case insensitive

Comment: @DaveRandom I thought of that: `$arrPerson['first'].'%%'.$arrPerson['last']`. Serialize is, imho, unnecessary overhead. String comparison could be made case-insensitive too.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fast and easy way that I know of, but here is a relatively simple way of doing it assuming that the ids for "similar elements" don't matter (i.e. you just need an ID period).

```
$final = array();
foreach ($array as $values) {
   $final[$values['first'] . $values['last']] = $values;
}
$array = array_values($final);
```

The last step is not strictly necessary .. only if you want to remove the derived keys.