# Adding Values them removing duplicates in a php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I need to process by adding the values, then removing any added duplicates.

Here's the Original Array...

```
Array (     
[0] => Array ( [PID] => 2872 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [PID] => 3145 [QTY] => 2 ) 
[2] => Array ( [PID] => 3107 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[3] => Array ( [PID] => 2739 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[4] => Array ( [PID] => 3137 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[5] => Array ( [PID] => 3107 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[6] => Array ( [PID] => 2739 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[7] => Array ( [PID] => 3107 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[8] => Array ( [PID] => 3137 [QTY] => 4 ) 
[9] => Array ( [PID] => 3551 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[10] => Array ( [PID] => 3107 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[11] => Array ( [PID] => 3107 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[12] => Array ( [PID] => 3137 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[13] => Array ( [PID] => 3551 [QTY] => 2 ) 
[14] => Array ( [PID] => 3136 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[15] => Array ( [PID] => 3137 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[16] => Array ( [PID] => 3032 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[17] => Array ( [PID] => 3551 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[18] => Array ( [PID] => 3107 [QTY] => 1 )
[19] => Array ( [PID] => 3459 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[20] => Array ( [PID] => 3141 [QTY] => 1 )
[21] => Array ( [PID] => 2724 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[22] => Array ( [PID] => 2743 [QTY] => 1 )
[23] => Array ( [PID] => 3139 [QTY] => 2 )
[24] => Array ( [PID] => 3137 [QTY] => 2 ) 
[25] => Array ( [PID] => 3107 [QTY] => 1 ) 
)
```

What I need to do is take this array and Add the [QTY] values from the same [PID] values then after this end up with an array like this...

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [PID] => 2724 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [PID] => 2739 [QTY] => 2 ) 
[2] => Array ( [PID] => 2743 [QTY] => 1 )
[3] => Array ( [PID] => 2872 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[4] => Array ( [PID] => 3032 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[5] => Array ( [PID] => 3107 [QTY] => 7 ) 
[6] => Array ( [PID] => 3136 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[7] => Array ( [PID] => 3137 [QTY] => 9 ) 
[8] => Array ( [PID] => 3139 [QTY] => 2 )
[9] => Array ( [PID] => 3141 [QTY] => 1 )
[10] => Array ( [PID] => 3145 [QTY] => 2 ) 
[11] => Array ( [PID] => 3459 [QTY] => 1 ) 
[12] => Array ( [PID] => 3551 [QTY] => 4 ) 
)
```

So add all the QTY then remove the duplicates.

I'm not quite sure the best way to proceed here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861682/php-multi-dimensional-array-remove-duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id just use a simple loop:

```
$combined = array();
// $org will be the original structure

foreach($org as $id => $data) {
   $pid = $data['PID'];
   if(!isset($combined[$pid])) {
     $combined[$pid] = $data;
   } else {
     $combined[$pid]['QTY'] += $data['QTY'];
   }
}

// return keys to normal indexs instead of the PID
array_values($combined);
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop over them, make a new array with PID as key and QTY as value so you can add the latter up.

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
    list($pid, $qty) = $row;
    $sums[$pid] += $qty;
}
```

Obviously you could throw an [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) in to suppress the notices.

And if you want your former array structure, convert it once more.