# How to remove repeat Json information?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, json

Database :

```
`--> product table
id  name      cid     uploadKey
1   Cemera     1       7365
2   Notebook   2       7222`

`--> category table
id    catename
1      canon
2      toshiba`


`--> attactments table
id      uploadKey       filepath
1       7365            /img/jdf.png
2       7365            /img/sdsd.jpg`
```

This code to create json file:

```
$_GET['id']="1";
 $json_response = array();
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $id=$_GET['id'];        
 $select = mysql_query("SELECT product.name,category.catename,attactments.filepath FROM product INNER JOIN category ON category.id = product.cid INNER JOIN attactments ON attactments.uploadKey = product.uploadKey where product.id='".$id."'  ");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select , MYSQL_ASSOC)) {       
        $json_response[] = $row;
         } 
    }
 echo $val= str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($json_response));
```

The result repeat information, how to remove repeat i want to show as below :

```
[{"name":"Cemera","catename":"canon","filepath":"/img/jdf.png"},{"name":"Cemera","catename":"canon","filepath":"/img/sdsd.jpg"}]
```

I want to show like this, how we edit it:

```
[{"name":"Cemera","catename":"canon","filepath":"/img/jdf.png","filepath":"/img/sdsd.jpg"}]
```

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507853/remove-duplicate-objects-from-json-array

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034696/rebuild-a-json-data-remove-duplicate-value-in-one-child-node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `GROUP_CONCAT()` **filepath**, try bellow code

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT product.name,category.catename,GROUP_CONCAT(attactments.filepath SEPARATOR ',') AS filepath FROM product INNER JOIN category ON category.id = product.cid INNER JOIN attactments ON attactments.uploadKey = product.uploadKey where product.id='".$id."'  ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select , MYSQL_ASSOC)) {   
   $row['filepath'] = explode(',',$row['filepath']);
        $json_response[] = $row;
         }
```

then you will get following result

```
{"name":"Cemera","catename":"canon","filepath":["\/img\/jdf.png","\/img\/sdsd.jpg"]}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you give me like this 
[{"name":"Cemera","catename":"canon","filepath":"/img/jdf.png","filepath":"/img/sdsd.jpg"}]

Comment: How do you hope to give different values in same key ? does it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

All Filepath should be comma separate using GROUP_CONCAT. Like this

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT product.name,category.catename,attactments.filepath 
FROM product 
INNER JOIN category ON category.id = product.cid 
INNER JOIN(SELECT uploadKey, GROUP_CONCAT(filepath SEPARATOR ',') FROM attactments GROUP BY uploadKey) a ON a.uploadKey = product.uploadKey where product.id='".$id."'  ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Put limit 0,1 at the end of query.
$select = mysql_query("SELECTproduct.name,category.catename,attactments.filepath FROM product INNER JOIN category ON category.id = product.cid INNER JOIN attactments ON attactments.uploadKey = product.uploadKey where product.id='".$id."' lomit 0,1 ");
```

I think it Helps..