# Filter 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array that looks a bit like this

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        ['id'] => 29
        ['name'] => john
        )
    [1] => array(
        ['id'] => 30
        ['name'] => joe
        ) 
    [2] => array(
        ['id'] => 29
        ['name'] => jake
        ) 
)
```

And that goes on for a while.

I've found the question elsewhere ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861682/php-multi-dimensional-array-remove-duplicate)) and ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)) But neither works.

With the first one I get the following array

```
array(
    [0] => 29
    [1] => jake
)
```

And with te second one it only filters out exact duplicates and not duplicates with jus the same `id`.

I want all the duplicates with the same `id` removed from the array, how do I do that?

Comment: So your result is expected to only contain `joe`?

Comment: @deceze no, `john` and `joe`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$filteredUsers = [];
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $filteredUsers[$user['id']] = $user;
}

// optionally:
// $filteredUsers = array_values($filteredUsers);
```

Comment: I have in fact posted variations on this answer many many times already, but I can't find any of them at the moment...

Answer (score 5):

Simple with PHP >= 5.5.0:

```
$result = array_column($array, null, 'id');
```

Optionally:

```
$result = array_values(array_column($array, null, 'id'));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want delete the duplicate and leave one alone:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'id' => 29,
        'name' => 'john'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 30,
        'name' => 'joe'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 29,
        'name' => 'jake'
    ) 
);

$filter = [];
$array = array_filter($array, function($a) use (&$filter) {
    $ret = !isset($filter[$a['id']]);
    $filter[$a['id']] = true;

    return $ret;
});
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/Jo5AL).

Otherwise:

```
$duplicate = array_count_values(array_map(function($i) {
   return $i['id'];
}, $array));

$array = array_filter($array, function($a) use ($duplicate) {
    return $duplicate[$a['id']] <= 1;
});

var_dump($array);
```

This will print:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(30)
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "joe"
  }
}
```