# Remove duplicates from multi dimentional array which include string and laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel

This is the multidimensional array and there's two column one is string and other one is laravel collection model.

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "email" => "myfirstemail@gmail.com"
    "user" => User {#2508 ▶}
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "email" => "myfirstemail@gmail.com"
    "user" => User {#2547 ▶} //laravel collection
  ]
]
```

I used [php multi-dimensional array remove duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861682/php-multi-dimensional-array-remove-duplicate) and it won't work for this.

I wan't to remove duplicate columns by email (no need to looked at the laravel **user** model.) Are there any inbuilt PHP function for this ?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs not work for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Laravel's `Collection::unique` method:

```
$unique = collect($yourArray)->unique('email');
```

By passing in `email` into the method, you're telling Laravel to look at that specific *field* in your dataset, rather than the data as a whole. You can then convert it back to an array using `toArray`.

```
$unique = collect($yourArray)->unique('email')->toArray();
```

You can also pass a closure to the `unique` method to allow you to define the value that you want to compare for each object to determine uniqueness:

```
$unique = collect($yourArray)->unique(function ($item) {
    return $item['email'];
});
```